# Translation of countries from java Locale.getAvailableLocales()

Tags: java, locale, language-translation

I'd like to have a list of all Countries. I found java Locale quite usable for this purpose. The `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` returns all installed Locales on the JRE.

The question is:

1. Is if safe to use across diferent JREs? Lets say OpenJDK, IBM Java, Oracle Java, 1.6, 1.7? Is there a better implementation?
2. It is possible to provide translation of `Locale.getCountry()` to a specific locale? I found if usable only for these few provided Locales `ENGLISH,FRENCH,GERMAN,ITALIAN,JAPANESE,KOREAN,CHINESE,SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE,TRADITIONAL_CHINESE,FRANCE,GERMANY,ITALY,JAPAN,KOREA,CHINA,PRC,TAIWAN,UK,US,CANADA_FRENCH`
   but what if i want to translate it to a `Locale("sk", "SK")` for Slovak. All countries keep its English name and only Slovak is translated properly: `SK EN:Slovak (Slovakia) FR:slovaque (Slovaquie) SK:Slovenčina (Slovenská republika)`. Whats the proper way to extend the java `Locale` directory of available Country/Locale translations with new translations.

---

```
private static final Locale SLOVAK = new Locale("sk", "SK");
Collection<?> COUNTRIES_LIST_EN = (Collection<?>) CollectionUtils
    .collect(Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH.getAvailableLocales()), new Transformer() {
      @Override
      public String transform(Object input) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s EN:%s FR:%s SK:%s", ((Locale) input).getCountry(),
                                         ((Locale) input).getDisplayName(),
                                         ((Locale) input).getDisplayName(Locale.FRANCE),
                                         ((Locale) input).getDisplayName(SLOVAK)));
        return ((Locale) input).getDisplayCountry();
      }
    });
```

**Output:**

```
JP EN:Japanese (Japan) FR:japonais (Japon) SK:Japanese (Japan)
PE EN:Spanish (Peru) FR:espagnol (Pérou) SK:Spanish (Peru)
 EN:English FR:anglais SK:English
JP EN:Japanese (Japan,JP) FR:japonais (Japon,JP) SK:Japanese (Japan,JP)
PA EN:Spanish (Panama) FR:espagnol (Panama) SK:Spanish (Panama)
CH EN:German (Switzerland) FR:allemand (Suisse) SK:German (Switzerland)
US EN:English (United States) FR:anglais (Etats-Unis) SK:English (United States)
SK EN:Slovak (Slovakia) FR:slovaque (Slovaquie) SK:Slovenčina (Slovenská republika)
```

Comment: `Locale.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ITALIAN)` and so on. But there are holes. However one may add one's own locales with own definitions. It stays messy.

Answer (score 1):

According to API  Locale.getAvaliableLocale returns at least a Locale instance equal to Locale.US. That is API does not guarantee that the result is the same for all JREs

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Java library:
https://github.com/rasmi-aw/Localisation-lib

```
// Fetch all countries with their cities and states
List<Country> countries = Localisation.getAllCountriesStatesAndCities();
```